# Tag Wikis should be indexed like Q&A in searches

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, search, tag-wiki

Pursuant to a [post I made about some questionable old questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122962/164572), we need the ability to have Tag Wikis be searchable.

For example, if the Tag Wiki for C++ has a list of books, a user searching for "C++ Books" should see the Tag Wiki page as one of the search items. It should look just like a question (more or less).

It shouldn't just be the preamble text at the top. A new user simply won't notice that; they're conditioned to ignore everything before the first item in the actual list. So the Tag Wiki page needs to appear in the list, with a title of some sort.

Comment: yes I agree, this is planned

Comment: @waffles any idea of what timescale this would be happening on? (weeks, months, or "6-8 weeks"?)

Comment: As long as we can suppress their inclusion in the results.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky its probably 4 weeks out, we are not talking multiple months.

Comment: @waffles you mean 6 to eight weeks-- _poke_

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126092/improve-visibility-of-related-alternate-tags  http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/links-to-related-tags  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags

Answer (score 9):

There is a lot of content in some of the Tag Wikis that if people could find in a search might keep them from creating duplicate questions.  This could be a poor man's canonical post, for those oft-posted duplicates.

I would think it would look like the questions do, with the excerpt being the Title and the tag info part being the content.  Label it with a **T:** and not have the votes/answers section.  Then just have the one tag in the tag section.

So something like this:

> **Java is an object-oriented language and runtime environment (JRE). Java programs ...**
>
> **T:** Java is a high-level, platform-independent, object-oriented programming language and runtime environment. The Java language derives much of its syntax from c and c++, but its object model is ...
>
> [java](/questions/tagged/java)