# Is there a way to search the text of a tag wiki page?

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag Wikis should be indexed like Q&A in searches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122963/tag-wikis-should-be-indexed-like-qa-in-searches)

I recently came across an inadvertently-bad tag on a question; it was an acronym collision. I was looking for the right tag for it, but I had some difficulty because it wasn't coming up by searching on tag names. Finally, with the following hack, I used Google to verify that there wasn't an appropriate tag, which explains why search on tag names was getting me nowhere.

```
site:stackoverflow.com/tags "tag wiki" [...search terms...]
```

The first term is the largest prefix that's possible. The second term excludes (most) all of the other content under that prefix, such as question lists.

I would much rather have a feature within the site that does this search rather than relying on hacks. I'm tagging this as a feature request because I don't think it exists. I'm asking it as a question, though: Is there already such a feature that I did not find?

This is not the same feature as that in [Tag Wikis should be indexed like Q&A in searches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122963/tag-wikis-should-be-indexed-like-qa-in-searches). In that question, they're asking for tag wiki pages to show up in ordinary searches. I would like a way to search for *just* the tag wiki pages, since that's what I was looking to edit. The search box on the main **Tags** page just searches through tag names, but it's the **Tags** page where I first went to search the tag wiki.

Comment: I'm really confused what your story has to do with tag wikis. It sounds like you were searching for an actual tag and not for text inside its wiki.

Comment: @animuson I was searching on the "full text" of the acronym. If there were already a tag name I wasn't finding it for some reason, I figured that it would appear in the wiki page for a tag that was hiding from me.