# New Badge Idea: "Prestative" -> "Fissured" -> "Superhero"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, badge-request, fastest-gun

**Prestative(Bronze):** Earned when you **answer correct**(accepted answer) 3 questions with a interval that is less than 120 minutes between each one.

**Fissured(Silver):** Earned when you **answer correct**(accepted answer) 5 questions with a interval that is less than 80 minutes between each one.

**Superhero(Gold):** Earned when you **answer correct**(accepted answer) 10 questions with a interval that is less than 45 minutes between each one.

Comment: We want to encourage quality, not quantity.  How would this do that?

Comment: Ok, a little change mensuring more quality, see edit.

Comment: You cannot post more than one answer per minute. Rate limiting is a good thing and there for a reason. These badges would discourage quality posts.

Comment: Accepted answers are not necessarily correct, and correct answers are not necessarily accepted.

Comment: To preempt, [voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). The downvotes probably mean that people disagree with your feature request. Judging by the upvotes on @psubsee2003's comment they disagree for that reason.

Comment: And logisitcally, it wouldn't work due to the rate limiting, plus the OP can't accept an answer for 15 minutes.

Comment: ok, then can you guys help me timing this better ?

Comment: All but the top 3 or 4 users each day post **far fewer** than 5 answers in a day. There is simply not enough time in a day to keep a day job and post that many answers. Yes, I post more, I may even hit 30 answers in a day, but **I am an exception**.

Comment: In other words, your badges would be *impossible* to achieve even on Stack Overflow. On any other site, which sees far fewer *questions to answer* per day, even the bronze badge would be a far stretch.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Frankly, I don't think the community wants this feature regardless of the implementation, so you are not going to get much support to rework this.  Plus I don't think there is any possible way to turn this into anything the community would support.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, and you are a "Superhero" thats why the badge creation, for recognize your hard work boy :D

Comment: @PauloRoberto: As I stated: it would be a stretch for me to even win the bronze badge. And I am a top-ranked answerer. Moreover, I'd be mortified to win any of these, to be frank. (And don't use *boy* in replies, in English that's rather.. condescending. I'm pretty certain I am older than you are, for one).

Comment: I know that this timing is horrible, sorry for that, but maybe you can help me in this timing

Comment: see my edit people, i have modified the timing and the quantity

Comment: recommended reading: [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773) and [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/165773). Foreseeing the fate of this feature request, a reading that will likely turn out useful in the future is: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It takes more than 10 minutes to provide a good answer to anything but the most basic questions, and most of those basic questions are duplicates.  So this would also contribute to more users answering questions that should be closed, rather than performing the appropriate moderation actions.

Additionally, answers are rate limited so the system will prevent someone from achieving this.  By including accepted answers as part of the criteria, you assume that accepted answers are correct (which they necessarily aren't correct and can be very wrong).  The accepted answer portion of the proposal wouldn't even be possible since it takes 15 minutes before the OP is even allowed to accept an answer.

But beyond fixing the timing, which you did in a later revision, to even be feasible, we want to encourage **quality**, not quantity. How would this do that? I can't see this would encourage anything but quick rapid fire answers and not focusing on anything approaching quality.

In the end, badges exist to do one of two things:

1. Badges should encourage positive behavior.  As I've mentioned above, this would do the exact opposite.
2. Badges should teach users about the features of this site.  Rapid fire answers is certainly not a feature of the site, so I can't see where it would be teaching anyone anything about how the site works.

Comment: i changed the question, see edit

Comment: @PauloRoberto changing the intervals doesn't make this idea better, just technically feasible.  My answer stands\

Comment: ok, i failed in this suggestion, sorry, maybe next time. im just trying to help

Comment: @PauloRoberto In your earlier question, Molot gave you the link to [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying), I suggest you spend time reading that.  We want to encourage people participating in meta as active Meta users are some of the best users on the other sites, but  throwing out rapid fire questions on meta like you did this morning and not the best way to start participating in meta.

Comment: i liked the info's, better use more ponies and waffles on the next suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

SO has quantity already - there's questions and answers posted at least every few seconds, pretty much constantly. What we really need to be looking at, IMO, is encouraging people to increase the quality of those questions and answers. This proposal does the opposite, even with the accepted answer change - it encourages a barrage of quick, low quality answers in the hope of getting them accepted.

For what it's worth, I don't think this proposal is salvageable via an edit either - whatever you put in, as long as the fundamental part of it remains (answering x questions in a time period) then, IMO at least, it's a detriment to SO rather than a benefit.

Comment: Why? at my point of view people need to think to answer and they will get smart and will have more knowledge trying to answer as possible

Comment: They will gain much more knowledge by carefully researching and answering a few questions, than skimming 20 and answering all of them in a limited and potentially bad way.

Comment: @PauloRoberto: I much rather garner upvotes for my thoughtful quality answers than to get a badge for shotgun-style answering with only-just-good-enough oneliners.

Comment: Maybe, i can change that times to improve quality...

Comment: @MartijnPieters and what about the good-shotgun answers ? the people that can think and give many good answers per day?

Comment: @PauloRoberto: We want to encourage quality answers over shotgunning. You need to take into account that badges encourage people to aim for them, and we **do not want** people to try and use shotgun tactics. It'll only lead to lower quality answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, but, badges for Sniping already exists, and badges for Shotgunning do not exists, if they are good and they can give a bunch of good answers, they should have recognition