# What are the fantasy secret hats you'd wish to get?

Tags: discussion, secret-hats, winter-bash

I had for some days the fantasy of getting a grinch hat. I know there is a hat when you only do upvotes in a day and believed it could make sense to have the same kind of hats for downvotes only. It would be the grinch hat. The programmer that ruined christmas.

What are the fantasy secret hats you'd wish to get?

Here's a small list I can come up with:

- Ohohoh: Gave a lot of reputation as a bounty on the 25th of December
- Rudolf Reindeer: Be the first to answer 5 or more questions
- The Horseman: Have 5 or more closed questions and 5 or more reopened questions in the same day (keep the balance)

Comment: I'd get the Grinch hat right now by voting to close this as Primarily Opinion Based. Right?

Comment: Ba humbug.  That said, please don't consider down votes to be a *negative* thing to the site.  They are a necessary part of helping the *good* content become more visible.

Comment: @MichaelT that's true unless the person downvote the good content and upvote the bad content! Not that I'm saying that someone should try that.

Comment: Any hat that gives me special abilities, like shooting fireballs or flying.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - did you try with Mario's Winged Cap? You may have to find the red switch though.

Comment: Note: since nobody posted that obvious one... I had to suffice with a second proposal. I have kept it separated from my first one, but if you prefer I will merge the two post.

Comment: Any hat awarded should still only be for actions that are good for the site; arguably some of the ones here are not (like ones that encourage very speedy but incomplete answering, or that promote gaming via sockpuppetry).

Answer (score 86):

[**YOU. SHALL NOT. PASS!!!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4UfAL9f74I)

Reject a suggested edit as spam, eventually leading to the deletion/destruction of the user's account.

[image]

Comment: Would be better as "You. Shall. Not. Pass!".

Comment: Oh, I guess I wasn't the only one. +1 for wizard's hat!

Comment: @BillyMailman Nah. It doesn't sound quite right.

Answer (score 52):

## BINGO!

[image]

Earned all hats in the same row, column, or diagonal.

---

Hats are arranged in a grid with 5 columns (B-I-N-G-O). Clear a row, column or diagonal and say "BINGO!". Only awarded once per user.

I realize this one stands no chance against Darth Vador, Gandalf, or even a LEGO brick. But looking at my earned hats this thought occurred to me. Requires careful arrangement of the hats on the WinterBash page.

Comment: Or it could be "clear *x* rows and/or *y* columns". Something about the pattern of visible/hidden tiles in the grid.

Answer (score 46):

### NERD

[image: glasses]

For hitting the rep cap on Christmas.

Comment: Now that would be a disappointing hat for me.....

Comment: I really like this one

Comment: @Bart: You never wore 2 glasses at the same time? You are not a nerd! :)

Comment: Aw man, I woulda gotten this hat :(

Comment: Please return these to @CodyGray when you're finished.

Answer (score 45):

### You don't know the power of the Dark Side

[image]

for when you do nothing but downvote and vote to close/delete posts in a single day.

Comment: Great "hat" idea, if litigation can be avoided, but it would need to be for something less easily gamed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard there are other Star Wars themed hats this year, so there seems to be precedent.  The criteria was somewhat tongue-in-cheek, but I think the idea of something around closing and deleting fits the title since it helps show the power (in terms of keeping the site clean) of closing and deleting (which some users regard as negative.)

Answer (score 36):

For ninja-editing a +1’d post, and finishing editing it, within 60 seconds of when it was first posted.

[image: Ninja graphic]

Comment: This just **has** to be mine.

Comment: sounds like @Jamal

Comment: Did anyone get this yet?

Comment: @AmalMurali [See for yourself](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/18399/cornbread-ninja).

Answer (score 35):

### The Nicolas Cage

[image]

Post an answer with a score of at least +5 to a meta question scored -5 or lower.

Comment: -1 Your argument is invalid.

Answer (score 28):

## Such Meta, so knowledge, much unicorn, wow.

*A post reaches 10 score on meta.*

[image: Such Meta, so knowledge, much unicorn, wow.]

---

## On Stack Exchange, Trogdor burns you

*Make edits that lead to a tag being cleaned at the end of the day*

[image: On Stack Exchange, Trogdor burns you]

---

## Here'ssssssssssssssssssssssss Jeff

*Upvoted question in the [plurals](/questions/tagged/plurals) tag*

[image: Here'ssssssssssssssssssssssss Jeff]

Answer (score 24):

### The Robot

Get caught by the bot detection software and <strike>fail</strike> pass the CAPTCHA human test.

[image]

Comment: Maybe one of [these](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=flight+of+the+conchords+robots&tbm=isch)?

Answer (score 21):

## Brick Hat

I'd like to have a LEGO hat, obviously.

[image]

Credit: [Jean Charles de Castelbajac](http://jc-de-castelbajac.com/).

Oh, and of course, as a reference to *the* classic 2×4 brick, it can be awarded for something like:

- Four meta posts with a score of 2+. In the same vein as Upboated, but harder to get, as downvotes on metas are rampant *and* there's generally very little activity on metas of smaller sites.
- Getting four bronze badges on a single day, and another four on another. We already have hats for silver and gold. But getting, for example, a Good/Great Answer/Question is actually not too hard for established users, because they often already have a bunch of posts sitting at 24 (or 98) votes, so they just need a stray upvote or two. However, getting four Nice Answers/Questions (or even *any* four bronze badges) on a single day, and then on another, would require quite some determination, in addition to leveling the playing field for new users.
- Two chat posts with four stars each.
- Any other combination of 2×4 somethings that the devs find worthy of a secret hat.

And before you say "make your mind up, pick one", I am actually posting a bunch of very different possibilities on purpose, just in case we do get the hat at some point in the future. It will then be harder for everyone (including myself) to figure out which option the devs have picked.

The picture for the hat could then be a simple 2×4 brick, too. The hats in the photos above are obviously way too detailed to work on small gravatars.

P.S.: in case you are not aware, there is a [Stack Exchange site for LEGO](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes)!

Comment: **The house Jack built** - Made 10 edits on own post.

Comment: I like retailcoder's suggestion a lot, but that one of course would be trivial to game. And we are talking secret hats here, which should be *harder* than normal ones.

Comment: +1 for the lego hat, I don't care about the criteria.  I want one almost as much as I want my Darth Vader hat.

Comment: [That is one seriously annoying website](http://jc-de-castelbajac.com/).  Not even going to discuss the Lego hats; they'll put anything on a model and call it couture.

Comment: Well. Yeah. Sometimes I feel like I'm in the wrong profession. On a second thought, I do get to put anything on a server and call it a website.

Comment: @TheGrinch That website is more than annoying... I'm going with hateful.

Comment: Well. I have to give credit. This is a legal issue, not a hat issue. I had never so much as heard of that website before posting this answer, and I already don't even remember its name. Can we please go back to focussing on hats? I've been focussing on websites all year long, I was hoping the Winter Bash would offer me a break. Plus I could have linked to something [way more annoying](http://www.dpgraph.com/), you know. Sturgeon's Law is recursive.

Answer (score 17):

## Ass Hat

[image]

Should be awarded when

- Only cast down votes in a day, with at least 5 down votes cast.
- Been down voted at least twice that day, and no up votes received.

Comment: Dude, that's NSFW.

Comment: Not everyone has an overly prude workplace.

Answer (score 16):

Autobot:

[image]

Take a bad post (score -3 or lower), and transform it into a good post (score +5 or more) by editing it.

Comment: There actually is an autobot hat already.

Comment: @Seth nope, it just appears in the sprites but no such hat

Comment: Hm. Are you sure?

Comment: Yup, unless you find someone with such hat? :)

Answer (score 14):

## Berserker Rage

[image: Viking Horns]

Use all your close votes in a single day, without nominating any closure due to duplication and without any of the closed posts being nominated for reopening.

Answer (score 14):

Why, the mad hatter of course, for voting to close a question after answering it and receiving +5 votes.
U MAD BRO?!

[image: http://images.huffingtonpost.com/gen/87687/original.jpg]

---

#### NOTE:

*This hat was used in the 2016 Winter Bash event (and reused in the 2017 edition). The unlock criteria was changed to a different one.*

T**he Hatter - Winter Bash 2016**
[image: The Hatter]

> Post a question 6:00pm in any timezone. The question must have at least one upvote.

Answer (score 13):

### The Cap

Hit each one of the caps (vote, delete, close) at least once during  WB. Possibly also the various flag caps, but that might make it really hard and destructive.

I had actually hit all three on MSO on one day during WB 2012, but there was no hat :(

Comment: You forgot star-cap in chat!

Answer (score 13):

### Father Christmas

[image]

For starting a bounty on Christmas day.

Answer (score 10):

### A pathway to many abilities some consider to be unnatural

[image]

Reaching 10k and thus [having access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Getting access to 10K tools doesn't *make you a moderator*... Nice idea still.

Comment: @retailcoder You're right, what it does is [give access to moderator tools](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Corrected

Answer (score 9):

## Fastest gun in the west

[image: Cowboy hat]

Be the first to answer a question, and have 2 other accounts post answers within 3 minutes from your answer.

Comment: detailed description of this hat is in [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers)

Comment: Hey, at least I get a chance of wearing a cowboy head ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Somebody HAD to do this.

**IT'S OVER NINE THOUSANDDDDD!**  (Vegeta hairs + Scouter Hat)

[image]

View the profile page of at least 10 different users whose reputation exceed 9k points.

and also:

**Super Sayajin**

[image]

You **are** [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

---

#### NOTE:

The "scouter hat" idea (minus the Vegeta's hairs) was used in the 2015 Winter Bash event. The unlock criteria was changed to a different one.

**It's Over 9000**

[image: It's Over 9000]

> Ask questions that accumulate 9000 views together. Can be earned in one question, or multiple. Potential limits not identified.

Later, in 2022, the Sayajin hair version was also implemented, sadly without the "You are Skeet" requirement...

[image]

Comment: I love the hat idea, but that's a really strange criterion. Maybe cast a vote that increases a user's reputation to > 9000?

Answer (score 8):

**Nabeshin Afro Hat / But you are still a newbie**

[image]

Award a bounty to an user account created less than 5 days ago.

Comment: One vote... so -there are- some Across members hiding between meta users..

Comment: Two votes. Hyatt, Excel... still missing Menchi. Don't tell me you have eaten it -again-!?!

Comment: That just asks for sockpuppetry..

Answer (score 8):

### Rebel With A Cause

[image]

Awarded for a controversial meta post scoring a minimum of both +10 and -10 with no more than 2 vote spread in either direction, as in +12 and -10 or +10 and -12.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The Capitalist Party (A direct response to the Communist party :) (//[OH GOD HOW DO I END THE PARENTHETICAL STATEMENT](https://xkcd.com/541))

[image: Capitalist Party]

At least double your rep from bounties

Comment: Ahah awesome, I'd upvote this multiple time.

Comment: It’s like when you have an abbreviation like say `Inc.` at the end of a sentence: you don’t repeat the terminating punctuation with a double dot/period/full stop. (In case it’s not obvious, it works the same way with parenthesized smileys. :)

Comment: @tchrist is that official? Can you show me the TED talk that came from?

Answer (score 7):

I think it would pretty sweet to have the avatar aang hat

[image]

Where the arrow and eyes were the only only part of the hat (the rest would be transparent, face left in image for context).

"During the event, have at least one question on both the main and meta site of an exchange be starred."

Answer (score 7):

### Sorting Hat

Vote to migrate your own question to a different site as selected by at least one other voter.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Communist party

[image: Communist party]

Award more than 90% of your reputation in bounty during winterbash.

Comment: Does a Communist partay stop?

Answer (score 5):

The Terminator.

Along the lines of Robocop, the Terminator is awarded if you use all your reviews in each of the review queues in one day.

Answer (score 5):

In a world where we could get per-site Hats, I would love to be this guy for the holiday period :

> [image]

Comment: But the Jon Skeet can only be awarded by Jon Skeet himself.

Comment: It could be awarded by answering a Jon Skeet question.

Answer (score 5):

### Grinch

[image]

Grinch mask.  Since it should be a secret I'd leave the requirements up to the team.

---

#### NOTE:

This idea (with a bonus free Santa's cap) was used in the 2016 Winter Bash event.

**No Longer Grinchy**
[image: No Longer Grinchy]

> Participate in successfully reopening or undeleting a question
>   The question [needs to remain open or undeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288356/152859). (When the hats award script is running, for this hat it's 10 minutes interval.)

Comment: Happy to see "No Longer Grinchy" for Hat Dash 2016!

Answer (score 4):

### The Mask

[image]

Again, qualifications should be a secret but I can think of a few ideas.

Answer (score 4):

### Holly Wreath (Ghost of Christmas Present)

[image]

Opposite of The Grinch. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Facepalm, for doing something facepalm worthy. Perhaps deleting your own post.

```
............................................________ 
....................................,.-'"...................``~., 
.............................,.-"..................................."-., 
.........................,/...............................................":, 
.....................,?......................................................, 
.................../...........................................................,} 
................./......................................................,:`^`..} 
.............../...................................................,:"........./ 
..............?.....__.........................................:`.........../ 
............./__.(....."~-,_..............................,:`........../ 
.........../(_...."~,_........"~,_....................,:`........_/ 
..........{.._$;_......"=,_......."-,_.......,.-~-,},.~";/....} 
...........((.....*~_......."=-._......";,,./`..../"............../ 
...,,,___.`~,......"~.,....................`.....}............../ 
............(....`=-,,.......`........................(......;_,,-" 
............/.`~,......`-...................................../ 
.............`~.*-,.....................................|,./.....,__ 
,,_..........}.>-._...................................|..............`=~-, 
.....`=~-,__......`,................................. 
...................`=~-,,.,............................... 
................................`:,,...........................`..............__ 
.....................................`=-,...................,%`>--==`` 
........................................_..........._,-%.......` 
...................................,
```

[ASCII Art Source](https://gist.github.com/protolif/2770546)

Comment: Try http://www.asciiflow.com/ to get a better demo-pic :)

Answer (score 2):

### Born to be Learn

First question with ten positive scores during WB.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Keeper**

Flag an AI produced answer during WB  and marked it as helpful.

[image]

Comment: that would add to the moderators burden to identify such flags.