# Is it a hat or a cake?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash-2015

I recently unlocked this hat:

[image]

From the [Winter Bash 2015](https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/), and I was wondering, because at first I thought it was a cake, and as not all of the things you can get are actually hats, I am wondering if this is actually meant to be a hat or a cake because I asked around and most think it's a cake, but nobody seems really too sure about that one so I would like some clarification. So, is it a hat, or a cake?

In other words, *can I eat it?* **;D**

Comment: It's a cat. And yes you can eat it.

Comment: In England, there is a "biscuit" (cookie) known as a [jammie dodger](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Jamiedodger.jpg) that looks oddly like this, which was my original interpretation. It is named sufganiyot, and so @πάνταῥεῖ's answer seems most appropriate.

Comment: nice question.......+1

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> *can I eat it?*

**Yes!**

[image: YiJiang eating the cake]

Comment: I was going to answer until I saw this. Clearly you can have your cake and eat it too.

Answer (score 14):

It's very probably a cake, since **sufganiyot** refers to this Jewish Hanukkah speciality mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270803/186472), which is kinda jelly filled cake/doughnut:

[image]

And also you can wear it as a hat now here. That's amazing, isn't it?

---

Well, regarding your question if you *"can eat it"*, the answer is simply **no**, unless someone finds a way you can physically consume internet pictures as food (that would be a really great thing, solving all of the starvation problems we have nowadays, Nobel prize worthy of course!).

Answer (score 12):

It seems to depend on your tastes.

Some eat hats and others wear cakes.
[image: Mike Pierce eats a hat]
[image: Harish Chandra Rajpoot wear a cake]

Comment: Very nice pictorial explanation...............+1 @Surb

Comment: Really, one can get confused. Earlier when I saw message it was 'you earned Sufganiyot on Mathematics!' I too got confused whether this was for eating as a cake or for wearing as a hat. You really clarified it. Thanks for your great answer!

Comment: This is the best pictorial explanation for **Sufganiyot as CAKE vs HAT**

Answer (score 8):

It's either a hat cake, or a cake hat, and going from google image search on either terms, unfortunately, doesn't clarify.

Regardless, the answer to *"Is it a hat or a cake?"* is **YES**.

Comment: Anything can be a hat if you put your mind to it.

Comment: @mmyers "...mind *under* it."

Comment: Nice diplomatic answer...........+1

Answer (score 5):

It's a sort of [jelly doughnut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufganiyah), and yes you can eat this bundle of fatty sugary goodness.  But be quick; Chanukah, the holiday with which they're associated, has already ended in several timezones.

[image: sufganiyot]