# Why are there two different hats for "Where in the World"?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016, secret-hats

I am wondering why some got a *moon* and others got a *sun* as **Where in the World** hat for the same action:

[image] **vs.** [image]

And is it possible two collect both e.g. from different sites? I only get moons…

I know that there has already been some spoilering [Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats).

Comment: Ten bucks says either timezones or hemispheres.

Comment: Have you tried flying to the southern hemisphere?

Comment: Not yet ;-) But I going to fly to Portugal tomorrow...So I will check the timezone theory at least…

Comment: If I recall correctly, previous years' dual-hats locked in whichever form you earned first, so that earning either on other sites always gave you the same form you've already earned. (This makes sense if you think of it as *one* hat with two forms.)

Comment: Just a note: last year's secret hat, for voting on the 21st (iirc), was a "the dress" hat, given out in 1 of 2 forms like this one.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'll take that bet (it's been proven by some of us that that is not the case).

Comment: @LegendaryDude Terms and conditions: bet is null and void if accepted after the correct solution has been revealed :)

Comment: This may be similar to last year's Flip Flop hat.

Comment: The penalty for having the "wrong" hat is banishment to the moon for a thousand years.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I could explain this to you but it is actually Quantum Mechanics. The hat type is not assigned until someone gets it.

Maybe you are interested to read the [implementation details](http://sklivvz.com/posts/i-built-a-hardware-rng-for-christmas)?

Comment: So it's randomly chosen which version you get?

Comment: *The hat is both a moon and a sun until you get the hat*

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ it's all part of a plan

Comment: @Sklivvz hmmmm very mysterious plan

Comment: So it's *not* timezones? Or hemispheres? Damn, that's my ten bucks gone then.

Comment: @Art it's cosmic dust.

Comment: I'm glad I got the moon version, it fits me much better.

Comment: @Won't same here!

Comment: But this is to be considered one hat or two different hats (I mean from the point of view of the community)?

Answer (score 9):

You can't collect the other version on different sites once you have the hat in one version. Think of it as *one* hat that has two forms. Whichever form you have first is the only form you can collect.

This has precedent from last year's [Flip Flop hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270788/is-there-a-list-of-what-each-of-the-winter-bash-hats-is-named-after/272558#272558) based on “[The Dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress)”: you were randomly assigned either a black and blue or white and gold hat, and once earned on one site, earning it on others would get you the same version.

Comment: [Relevant article](https://www.wired.com/2015/02/science-one-agrees-color-dress/).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's a secret within a secret. :)

Even in past years, SE never disclosed as to how they decided which of the two forms to assign to which user (they just said it was random). Now they're waiting to see who will guess that criterion, hence they keep reincarnating the hat every year.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor