# No No Longer Grinchy for reopening with Dupe Hammer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, dupehammer, winter-bash-2016

I noticed the [No Longer Grinchy hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/no-longer-grinchy):

> [image]

It clearly says: (emphasis mine)

> participate in **successfully reopening** or undeleting a question

I have reopened several questions today, latest is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92024/why-do-stack-overflow-cost-for-down-voting-a-answer-why-not-in-case-of-a-questi), using the Dupe Hammer, however I wasn't given the hat. Why is this?

P.S.
All the questions I reopened so far were then closed again, I did it as a cleanup process to remove the embedded markup of old duplicate closure, and put the notice in place instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because they are closed. The questions need to remain open (or undeleted) whilst the hat check runs, which is currently every 10 minutes.